# My sqldatareader does not work

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, connection, sqldatareader

I'm working on e-commerce website project but there is something I cannot solve. Here is my part of data access layer code.

```
try

 {
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Security.ConnString))

            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = (60 * 60);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xx", xx);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xx", xx);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ip", Ip);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionId", SessionId);

                    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        con.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (dr["Result"].ToString() == "1")
                            {
                                x = LoadDataRecordMusteri(dr);
                                x.Result = new ResultModel();
                                x.Result.Code = 56;
                                x.Result.Description = "kk";
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                x.Result = new ResultModel();
                                x.Result.Code = 86;
                                x.Result.Description = dr["Result"].ToString();
                            }

                            if (x.Durum == false)
                            {
                                x.Result = new ResultModel();
                                x.Result.Code = 24;
                                x.Result.Description = "xx";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            x.Result = new ResultModel();
                            x.Result.Code = 23;
                            x.Result.Description = "aa";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            x.Result = new ResultModel();
            x.Result.Code = 57;
            x.Result.Description = ex.Message;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Everything is great until `dr.Read()`. In sql when i execute it, it works; but anytime i debug my code it throws me:

```
else
                    {
                        x.Result = new ResultModel();
                        x.Result.Code = 23;
                        x.Result.Description = "aa";
                    }
```

I tried a lot of things but i couldn't do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you certain that `Login` returns results on the database/server that `Security.ConnString` is pointing to, with the parameters that you are passing?

Comment: Actually i think i got this. My encryption algorithm was crushed. Thanks for your answer.